# The settings icon on the Developer Story items has some screwy pixels

Tags: bug, design, developer-story

When I'm viewing my *Developer Story*, the little gear icon for getting the Edit/Delete menu on each item has some extra pixels underneath it, presumably from the CSS being misaligned with the texture atlas (or whatever you web guys call it). I guess nobody thought to test the site on a 4k monitor.

Platform: Firefox 49.0.1 on Windows 10

[image]

Comment: -1: No hand-drawn circles. (Seriously, though, +1)

Comment: Kudos to your observation skills

Comment: @ManojKumar I'm a graphics programmer. It's my living :-)

Comment: @DanHulme Great :) Looking forward to see some graphic lessons from you.

Comment: Thanks for the report. We're currently working through higher priority items but will take a look at this soon.

Comment: This seems to have gone away on its own.